# Is there any way to port a WPF application so it can run on mac-OS X?

Tags: wpf, windows, macos, porting

I have a GUI which I created using WPF I not want to port this so it's available for use on mac OS X.
I heard mono can be used but it looks like they [don't have any support for WPF's](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/wpf/) as of right now so any suggestions would be great Thanks.

Comment: You can try to have a look at `Xamarin` actually

Comment: doesn't Xamarin convert it only for IOS mobile?

Comment: @Ugur I don't think I managed to get my question through. I want to convert the WPF code to maybe swift or something so I can run it and get the same GUI on my mac OS.

Comment: As I know Xamarin is applicable only to mobile. Unfortunately doesn't support desktop OS'es.

Answer (score 3):

.NET Core 3.0 has WPF but **it works only for Windows platform**, so there is no build-in support for multi-platform desktop GUI.

You could try port WPF application using [Avalonia](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia), but I never tried it. Avalonia works with .NET Core 2.0, .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: Thank you so much I'll check it out.

Comment: @Andy it is rather beta than alpha. They state: "Avalonia is ready for General-Purpose Desktop App Development. However, there may be some bugs and breaking changes as we continue along into this project's development." https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/wiki/Projects-that-are-using-Avalonia and https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/2239

Comment: I stand corrected. Keen as I am on wpf and xaml I'm not so sure about adopting a beta open source project for a business app.

Comment: Avalonia is the way to go!